# Irreducible components of the closure of a locally closed subset

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, schemes, projective-schemes

I would like to ask for a reference of the following fact: the irreducible components of the closure of a locally closed subset are the closures of the irreducible components of the subset.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on that topic, but isnt it by definition? I mean you have your locally closed W= U $\bigcap$V with U open and V closed. By taking V=$\overline{W}=\bigcup V_i$ a decomposition in irredicuble subsets.
Then you have that $W=\bigcup V_i\cap U$ and $\overline{V_i\cap U}=V_i$.

If I am wrong, I am almost sure that in the Harthsorne you can find something.

Comment: Thank you. Could not we have that $V_i\cap U$ is empty for some $i$?

Comment: I dont think so. If you have $V_i\cap U=\emptyset$ then $V_i\cap W$ is also empty because $W\subset U$ and since $V=\overline{W}$, then $V_i$ wouldnt be an irreducible component of V. I hope I helped you.